# Web.config Transform variables

Tags: web-deployment-project, msdeploy, webdeploy, web-config-transform

Is it possible to include variables in a web.config transform file? For each environment, I have basically the same transform, just with different values.  For example, for the development environment, I'd have...

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
    <appSettings>
        <add key="serverName" value="server1" xdt:Transform="Replace" xdt:Locator="Match(key)" />
        <add key="serverPath" value="\\server1" xdt:Transform="Replace" xdt:Locator="Match(key)" />
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

And for the QA environment, I'd have...

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
    <appSettings>
        <add key="serverName" value="server2" xdt:Transform="Replace" xdt:Locator="Match(key)" />
        <add key="serverPath" value="\\server2" xdt:Transform="Replace" xdt:Locator="Match(key)" />
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

The only difference is the value for server1 vs server2.  This is a simple example, and in reality, I use the server value multiple times in the transform.  Is there any way to declare a variable in the transform file to be used multiple times?  Something like...

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
    <property name="server" value="server2" />
    <appSettings>
        <add key="serverName" value="${server}" xdt:Transform="Replace" xdt:Locator="Match(key)" />
        <add key="serverPath" value="\\${server}" xdt:Transform="Replace" xdt:Locator="Match(key)" />
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did something similar to this a few months ago. Example is at http://www.geoffhudik.com/tech/2010/10/19/webconfig-automation-with-t4-and-a-macro.html

Comment: This is a link-only answer to your own blog. Please republish the relevant material here so that in the event your blog ever goes offline, your answer remains useful to other viewers.

Answer (score 4):

this is not supported with web.config transformations. One thing that you could take a look at is creating a [T4 Template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx) which can be used to generate your web.config transformations. So the idea being that you place the variables in the T4 template, and it will spit out the web.debug.config/web.release.config/etc. Then when you package/publish it will just pick up the transform file which was produced as the T4 output.

I wouldn't mind helping you with such a thing if you can provide some concrete examples of this being useful.